# Retain leading blank when reading raw data using datalines method

Tags: sas

According to below output, the leading to trimmed automatically for the fourth observations. **cdefg** -> cdefg.

**Question: How can i retain the leading blank.**

```
data chr2;
    input string $ 1-25;
    strLen = length(string);
    compblStr = compbl(string);
    compblLen = length(compblStr);
    datalines;
abc 5678
abcd  78
 bcdef 8
  cdefg  
;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use $charW. informat to keep training blanks. This informat preserves leading and trailing blanks.

```
data chr2;
    input string $CHAR25.;
    strLen = length(string);
    compblStr = compbl(string);
    compblLen = length(compblStr);
    datalines;
abc 5678
abcd  78
 bcdef 8
  cdefg  
;
```